# Replace occurence with its number (look and say numbers as a regex in Java)

Tags: java, ruby, regex, count

I would like to get to know an equivalent of this Ruby code in Java:

```
str.gsub(/(.)\1*/) do
    "#{$&.size}#{$1}"
end
```

What it does is replacing the occurence of equal consecutive characters with the number of repeats and the character itself.
For example: "111" will change into "31", because there are three ones, "111223" wil change into "312213", because there are three ones, two twos and one three etc. It is basicly called "look-and-say" numbers. I would like to acomplish this using regexes, possibly without any loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use the code based on `Matcher#appendReplacement`:

```
String s = "111";
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(.)\\1+").matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(result, m.group().length() + m.group(1));
}
m.appendTail(result);
System.out.println(result.toString()); // => 31
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/3iAIkQ)

Answer (score 0):

Consider this documented example

```
    //For concatenating output
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    //The Matcher finding digits followed by at least one of the same
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\d)\\1+").matcher("1112222233");
    //While consecutive digits found
    while(m.find()) {
        //Append length of match (= number of same digits)
        sb.append(m.group().length())
        //append the matched character / digit
            .append(m.group(1));
    }
    //output
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Your solution does not keep non-repeating characters in the source. Try `111222abcDDD` for example.